# Как из списка файлов изображений с полными путями в объекте TStrings, вывести в TListView изображения в виде thumbnails?

Tags: delphi

Как из списка файлов изображений с полными путями в объекте `TStrings`,
вывести в `TListView`  изображения в виде `thumbnails`?

```
var
  SR: TSearchRec; 
  FilesStrings: TStrings; 
  SelectedPath: string; 
begin 
  FilesStrings:=TStringList.Create; 
  SelectedPath := 'c:\imagefolder'; 
  if FindFirst(SelectedPath + '.', faAnyFile - faVolumeID - 
        faDirectory - faHidden - faSysFile - faArchive, SR) = 0 then repeat 
    FilesStrings.Add(SelectedPath + SR.Name); 
  until FindNext(SR) <> 0; 
  FindClose(SR); 
  FilesStrings.Free; 
end;
```

Все имена изображений в `FilesStrings`. Также я создал на форме `ImageList1`, `ListView1`.

Comment: Приведите пример вашего кода, что вы пытались сделать, что у вас не получилось, а также пример входных данных и выходных данных.

Comment: SR: TSearchRec;
  FilesStrings: TStrings;
  SelectedPath: string;
begin
  FilesStrings:=TStringList.Create;
  SelectedPath := 'c:\imagefolder';
  if FindFirst(SelectedPath + '*.*', faAnyFile - faVolumeID - faDirectory
    - faHidden - faSysFile - faArchive, SR) = 0 then
  repeat
    FilesStrings.Add(SelectedPath + SR.Name);
  until FindNext(SR) <> 0;
  FindClose(SR);
    FilesStrings.Free;
end; Все имена изображениий в FilesStrings. Также я создал на форме ImageList1, ListView1.

Comment: Вы можете отредактировать свой вопрос, нажав кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/871840/edit), расположенную под самим вопросом. Пожалуйста воспользуйтесь ей для добавления информации из вашего комментария. Также вы можете использовать сочетание `Ctrl+K`(или нажать на кнопку с фигурными скобочками) чтобы пометить участок текста как пример кода.

Comment: Список файлов у вас уже есть, вы на верном пути, продолжайте!